Board-to-Board high current pin header for planar PCB winding
I am trying to stack two boards having planar interleaved windings. I intend to use a board-to-board single-pin contact, but unable to find any suitable pin headers for the purpose. Several board-to-board connectors are available but mostly of very small current rating and several contact pins. My target current rating is around 30A. I want to use pins of the sort that are shown in the image (I assume these are contact pins connecting turns of one PCB to another one stacked on it). Does anyone have any idea about these contact pins? Suggestions on alternatives for connecting stacked planar winding PCBs are also welcome. 

The picture looks like millmax nail head pins

Suggestion: bare copper wire soldered in place.

Mac-eight is the expert company in high-current PCB terminals. Browse through their catalog for ideas.

Solution 1:

Install broaching PCB PEM nuts on each hole Pick ones whose thickness results in the desired spacing between boards
Stack the boards
Insert a long screw from the top with a smaller diameter than the thread of the nuts, so that it can slide in unimpeded
Finally, insert it to your final output conductor (e.g. a bus bar pr a motherboard)
Fasten that screw to a nut at the bottom to clamp all the boards an the final conductor tightly, so that current flows primarily from nut to nut (rather than through the screw).


{Source: my picture}

Solution 2 - backplane with quick-connect disocnnects:

Install flush right-angle male quick-connect disconnects on each PCB
Create a motherboard that sits vertically against the stack
Install on that motherboard vertical female quick-connect disconnects
Insert each daughterboard into the motherboard to create a stack
Install the stack of daughterboards into the ferrite core

